# How to convert const char * into a char [] array in objective C

Tags: objective-c, c

I basically want to create a `char[]` array and copy the contents of the `char *` pointer into it.

Here is my code

```
NSString * userId = @"1001";

const char * userIDUTF = [userId UTF8String];

char array1[userid.length];

memcpy(array1, userIDUTF, userId.length);
// array1 prints "1" i.e only the first element of userId
```

I want the entire content of the userId into `array1[]` array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to null-terminate array1, and using -length on the NSString to get the length of the UTF8 string is potentially unreliable. Some characters may have been dropped for whatever reason. Use strlen instead.

Comment: strcpy will fix your problem by automatically null terminating